# Badges In Destiny 2 Crucible

Tags: destiny-2

While playing the Crucible PvP in Destiny 2, I keep getting these badges in the top center of my screen. They're obviously for doing things, like getting a double kill you get, "Double Down". But some of them are quite confusing. Ones such as, "I Live here Now", and, "Wrecking Crew", confuse me. Then there's also the yellow and black ones that I hardly ever see. Can somebody please either direct me to a list of these badges, or give a list of them along with what they represent?

Comment: You can't check them in game? Usually any badges you get tell you what you did to get them.

Comment: No you can't. You see them for a second and then they're gone. I've looked. @Frank

Comment: Looks like a partial list can be found [here](https://samurai-gamers.com/destiny-2/pvp-medals-list/#PvP_Medals).  Note some aren't known or confirmed.

Comment: They don't earn you anything so they don't really matter, just telling you that you did 'X thing' in Crucible. They're also self explanatory for the most part.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There is a list of the badges and what they mean in game which is under Crucible in the Triumphs screen.

Here is a list of them collected by the playing community:

- **Best Served Cold** - Killed an enemy player who killed you
- **Blood for Blood** - Killed an enemy player who just killed one of your allies
- **Cold Fusion** - Go on a Fusion rifle spree.
- **Combined Fire** - Kill an enemy player by shooting at them as a team.
- **Counter Attack** - Get a kill while being the last guardian standing.
- **Crushed Them** - Win a match with a large margin of victory.
- **Barricade Breaker** - Killed an enemy Titan and destroy their barricade.
- **Dodge This** - Killed an enemy Hunter during their dodge animation.
- **Rift Breaker** - Killed an enemy Warlock during their rift phase.
- **Dominant Advantage** - Score five Advantage or Power Play kills before the opponent recaptures a zone.
- **Pitch Perfect** - Defeat an opponent with Hammer of Sol at a distance greater than 30 meters.
- **Everything Looks Like a Nail** - Defeat three opponents within a single Hammer of Sol activation.
- **Regent** - Killed two enemy Guardians with a sword.
- **Annihilation** - Land final blows on the entire enemy team before any of them respawn.
- **Double Play** - Kill 2 enemy players in rapid succession.
- **Triple Play** - Kill 3 enemy players in rapid succession.
- **Lights Out** - Kill 4 enemy players in rapid succession.
- **We Ran Out of Medals** - In a single life, defeat 20 opposing Guardians.
- **Fight Me!** - Deal the most damage in a match.
- **Flag Bearer** - Secure the most capture zones during the match
- **Reclaimer** - Recapture a zone within 15 seconds of it being captured by your opponents.
- **Gangs All Here** - All allies must survive at the end of a Countdown round.
- **Hawkeye** - In a single life, defeat two opponents with precision Hand Cannon final blows.
- **Hurricane** - Kill three enemy Guardians in a single Arcstaff super activation.
- **I Live Here Now** - Hold two or more zones for at least 1 minute.
- **Lethal Instinct** - Defeat an opponent within 2 seconds of activating Golden Gun.
- **Lightning Strike** - Defeat an opponent within 3 seconds of activating Arc Staff.
- **Never In Doubt** - Win a match in which your team never trailed.
- **Handful of Bullets** - Kill three enemy Guardians in a single Golden Gun super.
- **Not So Fast, My Friend** - Defeat an opposing Guardian using your Super while their Super is active.
- **Direct Hit** - Kill an enemy player instantly with one shot from a Grenade Launcher.
- **Power Overwhelming** - As a team, defeat all 4 opposing Guardians at least once during a single Power Play.
- **Quick Strike** - Get the first kill in a game ([to be confirmed](https://www.reddit.com/r/DestinyTheGame/comments/90ge8a/destiny_2_medal_descriptions_are_now_in_the_api/e2qjrxy/)).
- **Ruthless** - Perform a 5-kill streak.
- **Unyielding** - Perform a 10-kill streak.
- **Shutdown** - Kill an enemy player who is on a kill streak.
- **Splash Damage** - Kill 2 or more enemy players with a Rocket Launcher.
- **The Cycle** - In a single match, land at least one final blow with each class of weapon (Kinetic, Energy, Power) and ability (Melee, Grenade, Super).
- **Wrecking Crew** - As a team, defeat 7 opposing Guardians without any of your team dying.
- **Lethal Cadence** - In a single match, defeat 7 opponents with Pulse Rifle final blows.
- **Undertaker** - Land all knockout blows on the opposing team in a single round.
- **Time and a Half** - Win a match in overtime.
- **Undefeated** - Complete a match in which you are never defeated by an opponent.
- **Sub machinist** - In a single life, defeat 2 opponents with Submachine Gun final blows.
- **One for Each of You** - In a single life, defeat two opponents with precision Hand Cannon final blows.
- **Field Scout** - In a single match, defeat 5 opponents at long range with Scout Rifle final blows.
- **Striker Special** - In a single activation, defeat two opponents with Shoulder Charge, then a third with Fists of Havoc.
- **Absolute Force** - Defeat two or more opponents in a single Fists of Havoc slam.
- **Flying Fortress** - Defeat an opponent with a Shield Rush within 3 seconds of defeating an opponent with a Sentinel Shield melee.
- **Perfect Guard** - Block fatal damage within 2 seconds of activating Ward of Dawn.
- **Longbow** - Defeat an opponent with Shadowshot at a distance greater than 30 meters.
- **Falling Star** - Defeat an opponent with Brimstone while Daybreak is active.
- **Defying Gravity** - In a single Daybreak activation, defeat two or more opponents without touching the ground.
- **Singularity** - Defeat an opponent with a Nova Bomb Vortex.
- **From Downtown** - Defeat two or more opponents with a Nova Bomb that was in the air for at least 5 seconds.
- **Thunderstruck** - Defeat an opponent with Landfall while casting Stormtrance.
- **Lightning Storm** - Defeat two or more opponents in a single Stormtrance activation.
- **Entangled** - Defeat a tethered opponent within 5 seconds of casting Shadowshot.

Thanks to Timmy Jim for the link to the [Destiny 2 Wiki](https://samurai-gamers.com/destiny-2/pvp-medals-list/#PvP_Medals)

[Reference](https://www.reddit.com/r/DestinyTheGame/comments/90ge8a/destiny_2_medal_descriptions_are_now_in_the_api/) to medal details from the game's API.

Comment: Crushed them is beating the enemy by so many points, maybe double their score, and doesn't seem to make any difference whether you hit time or score limit to win. Handful of bullets I can confirm is 3 kills with the gunslinger super.

Comment: They're all listed in the Crucible Triumphs screen now :)

Comment: Perfect. Question now obsolete?

Answer (score 1):

If you log into [DestinyTracker](http://www.destinytracker.com) you can find the medals you have earned plust lost of other stats related to PvE and PvP.

For some reason Bungie no longer lists the criteria for these medals on the official app for D2 as they did with D1 and the definitions on the wiki are what players have worked out for themselves.

To add to the list in the accepted answer as best as I can work out.

**Fight Me** : finish a match with the highest damage (not all match  types show damage inflicted on the final screen but I think it is counted for all match types)

**Wrecking Crew** : get 5 (I think) kills as a team without anyone on your team dying

**Annihilation** : wipe the enemy team yourself ie kill the whole enemy team within one regeneration cycle.

**The Gang's All Here** : finish a competitive match with none of your team knocked out.

**Survivor** : Finish a round without dying

**undefeated** : finish an entire match without dying #(and maybe also win the match)

**Supremacy Perfection** : get  100% crest recovery ie recover 1 crest for every kill you make

**Not So Fast My Friend** : kill an enemy while they are activating their super or otherwise prevent their super from activating.

**My Crest is My Own** : either recover your own crest in supremacy   or compete a match without having your crest taken (not sure which)

There area also medals for streaks with particular weapon types, Field Scout, Sub Machinist, Assault Specialist etc etc

There are at least 52 different medals. As far as I can  tell the red/white ones are for individual achievements or kinetic/energy weapon kills regardless of overall result. The orange/grey ones are for team achievements and special/super/ability kills and the yellow ones are for rare achievements.

I'm also pretty sure that there are some medals which don't appear on Destiny tracker. I'm pretty sure there is one for winning by the mercy rule (ie get a certain number of points ahead by a certain time).

Answer (score 0):

Crushed them means you laid waste in the crucible by 20 or more. Guess.            Counter attack is killing the agressor supered countering with your super        fight me is highest kill count vs anyone any team best of best . You may or may not need to be getting slaughtered to get it.                              Dominant advantage is holding 3 zones for a sustained period of time Maybe 1/2 the match . Ive aquired all of them